# How to prove about roots of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Could someone give me a hint or prove this.

Let $n$ is an even number and polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ such that $a_n>0$ and $a_0<0$. Prove that there are two different roots which is real number.

Comment: Have you tried putting $P(0)$ and $P(M)$ for $M$ a sufficiently large number and $P(-M)$?

Comment: Since $n$ is even, you know the limits as $x\to\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$. Since $a_0<0$ you know that this continuous function at zero is negative. All you need now is the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I got it, thank everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This polynomial equation if $n$ is even has at least two real roots one in $(-\infty,0)$ and the other in $(0, \infty)$. This so by IVT as $p(-\infty)=+\infty, p(0)=a_0<0, p(\infty) =+\infty.$

Comment: Sorry, if we let $n$ is positive even we can do the same thing ?

Comment: For a polynomial $n$ has to be a positive integer.